# How to add boost.asio to the windows universal app project?

Tags: c++, win-universal-app, boost-asio

How can I add boost.asio to a windows universal project to it's shared components?

Do I need to create separate project and include the header files there or is there more simple way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I can't get into the specifics of Universal Apps too much (I'm not an authority on that subject), I can tell you that this: `boost::asio` is a header only library. That means that by simply including the headers into your C++ project, that code is merged directly into your main assembly. I highly recommend using it in this way.

If you're going to include this header only library into another DLL that you then include in your main app, things are going to messy. First, you have the headache of building binaries for each target (x86, x64 and ARM) and maintaining those dependencies but beyond that, the real headache is what you need to go through to make `boost::asio` function when being loaded from a shared assembly.

In order to do this, you need to define a special static member inside `::asio` called `winsock_init` in your code. `::asio` uses an internal, static customized reference counter using interlocked exchanges to track its own usage. When the counter is incremented beyond zero, calls to things such as `WSAStartup()` are made to ensure that the library plays nice with Winsock. When the counter reaches zero again, `WSACleanup()` is called again for the same reasons.

The structure `winsock_init` circumvents this functionality, so it's up to you to correctly, manually call these functions **from within your shared assembly**, otherwise you're going to completely break ASIO AND your application will fail compliance testing for app store deployment.

Also, whenever you try to wrap `::asio` into a shared assembly you need to include special source files **one time only, within the dll** and then you need to define a bunch of special boost config variables both in this DLL project and any project that uses this `::asio` dll.

My advice again is to simply include the headers alone in your primary assembly and then you're not introducing all of these headaches. Another alternative is to simply use C++/CLI or Managed C++, whatever it's called these days, and directly access the .NET socket classes from within your mixed C++ code.

[See here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.optional_separate_compilation) for more details about compiling ASIO into a separate assembly if you really want to suffer all the pain I've described.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But actually my question was more universal app oriented. There there is shared component which holds the shared classes and I didn't know how to add the library there. But after some research I found that you simply add the library twice. Once in the desktop application and once in the mobile. and the shared classes used it directly from there. 
Thanks

Comment: @Gabrielkotev Alright great, but regardless of what type of application you use ASIO in, everything I said here applies. Consider posting an answer to share your complete solution and marking it as correct to close out this question.